# Getting the array value from an Object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to get the 
['text'] value from an array object.
When I try to print_r($item), I get this as output:

```
ToDo Object
(
[data:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 128
        [user_id] => 6785
        [view_stat] => 0
        [position] => 12
        [text] => 3rd try
        [dt_added] => 2012-07-17 04:29:08
        [tick] => 0
        [temp_view] => 6785
        [viewer] => 6785
    )
)
```

how to get the [text] value in php?? thanks

Comment: Use the methods that the `ToDo` object has... it should provide an interface to access this information.

Comment: `print_r(get_class_methods($item))` to see if there is a public method to get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Since those are private variables, you can't!

You need to create a public function inside the class, that will return the specific data needed:

```
public function getText () {
  return $this -> text;
}
```

And outside the class you can retrieve it like this:

```
$class = new ToDo();
$myText = $class -> getText();
```

Comment: if the problem is just the private thing, can I just change the private var to public? how to access it? I really don't know the syntax. thanks!

Comment: I just wrote you the full syntax. Paste 1st code into your `ToDo` class and the second one outside, where you need to access it.

Comment: Yes. You can simply change from private to public and then access it as $class->data->text;

Comment: Of course, but I wouldn't suggest that. It's better to keep variables private and make public functions that output the variables. You get more control over the data given.